# How to generate custom suggestion list in DHTMLX combo

Tags: javascript, combobox, dhtmlx

The auto-suggestion list provided by the DHTMLX Combo is updated on every keystroke but apparently uses prefix-matching only. How do I change the logic to match anywhere in the option's text.

E.g. in the below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wra8etjw/2/

I would like the suggestion for "Three" to show up even when I type "ee" in the box. I've read the documentation on [custom filtering](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/combo__filtering.html) but neither the custom filtering approach nor the user-defined function got me anywhere.

I am using a DHTMLX Combo box in a rudimentary way. Namely the options are present as a literal in the HTML file served from the server (they are pretty static), so the `onDynXLS` is never fired (there's no Ajax going on).

My other idea was to capture the current value that the user is typing, save it to some global variable and then provide a user-defined filtering function that would return true on all values in which the current value is present (not just as a prefix). This also failed as apparently the user-defined filtering function is only called on page load, not on every keystroke inside the input text. Moreover, I don't know which even to use to capture key strokes inside the Combo's input text and obtain the current value.

So my questions are:

1. how to make the list of suggestions show values where the current text exists as a substring anywhere in them, and not just as a prefix?
2. how to capture keystrokes in the Combo's input text and obtain the current value as the user is typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > 1. how to make the list of suggestions show values where the current text exists as a substring anywhere in them, and not just as a prefix?

Use `enableFilteringMode('between')`

> > 2. how to capture keystrokes in the Combo's input text and obtain the current value as the user is typing?

Easiest way IMO is to attach a handler in the underlying `input` element the Combo uses.

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7spp4L5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

> > how to make the list of suggestions show values where the current text exists as a substring anywhere in them, and not just as a prefix?

Unfortunately such feature is not available without the modification of the dhtmlxCombo source code
or you should use the server-side filtering mode, so you will be able to use the onDynXLS event solution.

> > how to capture keystrokes in the Combo's input text and obtain the current value as the user is typing?

You may try to use the "onKeyPressed" event:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxcombo_onkeypressed_event.html